# Why am I getting 'A Term Expected' Error for CSS file?

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

I'm getting an error inside a `CSS` file for attribute `background-clip: padding-box;`

I'm using **v8.0 PhpStorm** and looking for a work-around to eliminate the Red Error indicator for this.

Unable to find it in <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Inspections</kbd> to by-pass it, of course - but thought to look anyway.

Perhaps I'm looking for the wrong item...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I plugged your attribute into my PHPStorm 8.0.1 and it's quite happy. There's more to this than you've posted.

Comment: Perhaps you missed an opening bracket or something?

Comment: Post yer code brehtherin.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I did miss a missing bracket in the line above. I apologize for even posting this, but my focus was on the red underline alone and my eyes didn't even register the line above...

Thanks again.